# Is the sequence of random numbers generated with a given seed guaranteed to be the same across versions of the standard?

Tags: c++, random, standards, std, random-seed

If I seed the random number generator from the C++ standard library with a given number (say `seed = 1`), and generate a sequence of random numbers, is this sequence guaranteed to be the same in future versions of the standard?

Does the C++ standard offer guarantees on this?

Comment: I believe this question has the same answer as whether any given behavior currently defined by the C++ standard will be retained in future versions for backward compatibility.  That is a question that only the C++ Standards Committee can answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be pedantic, nothing is guaranteed about future versions of the standard, including the idea that there may be a future version of the standard.

Now, on to your real question. "The" random number generator in the C++ standard library? There's a lot of them. `rand` is not one of them :-)

There are "Random number engines", that generate "random sequences of bits". They include:

- `linear_congruential_engine`
- `mersenne_twister_engine`
- `subtract_with_carry_engine`

The section [rand.predef](http://eel.is/c++draft/rand.predef) gives required results for specific random number engines. That tells you that they're supposed to be portable. [ Thanks to @HowardHinnant for the reference. ]

The distributions, on the other hand (`uniform_int_distribution`, etc) CAN differ from implementation to implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The question of whether a C++ random number sequence will remain the same sequence in *future versions of the standard*, is just like the question of whether any given behavior currently defined by the C++ standard will be retained in future versions for backward compatibility. That is a question that only the C++ Standards Committee can answer. (This was a comment of mine, moved to an answer.)

Comment: The standards committee does try to maintain backwards compatibility, but `std::random_shuffle` is a case-in-point of them breaking backwards compatibility.  (Titus Winters seemed a bit irked over that one.)  If one's code or test code requires a random number generator to be future-proof, the best way to do so is to write your own random number generator.